# Correct use of PDO procedure not using global

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having a play around with PDO and currently have the following code but I am getting `Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object` and I don't want to use global.

Do I use a class or do I pass it as a variable?

**Config.php**

```
function connection()
{
    try
    {
        $host   = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = '';
        $dbpass = '';
        $dbname = '';
        $dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $dbname.";", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        return $dbConnection;
    } catch (PDOException $error)
    {
        echo $error->getMessage();
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**Functions.php**

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$db =  connection();

function listCars()
{
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` `rego` `engineSize` `type` `colour` `year` `additionalFeatures` FROM `cars`");

    $result = $query->fetchAll();

    return $result;
}

?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php  
    include('assets/misc/functions.php');

    var_dump(listcars());                

?>
```

Comment: That depends on the architecture of your site / application. In this case it looks like passing as a parameter is the best choice as you are not using any classes.

Comment: You catch exceptions when you connect, which is good, but before you use your connection in `Functions.php` you should check the return value of `connection()` to make sure you have a connection. I also really don't like that you're actually doing things in your `Config.php`, that's for settings. Move the action to `Functions.php`.

Comment: The error message is because `$db` is a global variable, you have to use `global $db` to be able to use it in a function. Or, as in the answer below, use it as an argument to the function.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks :) I agree I am just putting ideas around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load the db variable into your function, in Functions.php, look at this:

**Functions.php**

```
    include('config.php');

    $db =  connection();

    function listCars($db){

        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` `rego` `engineSize` `type` `colour` `year` `additionalFeatures` FROM `cars`");

        $result = $query->fetchAll();

        return $result;
    }

?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php  
    include('assets/misc/functions.php');

    var_dump(listcars($db));                

?>
```

However, if you're looking for a more OOP approach, try the following:

```
<?php 

    class Cars {
        protected $db;

        public function __construct(PDO $db){
            $this->db = $db;
        }

        public function listCars(){
            $query = $this->db->prepare("... query ...")->execute();
            return $query->fetchAll();
        }
    }

    include('config.php');

    $cars = new Cars(connection());

    try {
        var_dump($cars->listCars());
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, I've updated my answer with a more OOP approach, as I figured if OP is using PDO, they probably want to go down the class route :)

Comment: Thanks Phil, Why am I now getting Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object on line 15? https://www.dropbox.com/s/kizy0j7zjf1b3n1/Screenshot%202014-09-05%2010.28.50.png?dl=0

Comment: Directly after line 15, can you add this: `var_dump($this->db); exit;` then post the result please?